# C++ : Why do I have to add a boolean expression?

Tags: c++, while-loop, logical-operators

The code is:

```
  int main() {
    int n, largest = 1;
    cout << "enter :" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int i = n - 1;
    while(i > 0) {
       if (n % i == 0){
            largest = i;
       }
       i--;
    }
    cout << largest << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
  }
```

Why do these error occur? This code keeps making errors and my professor said that I should add a boolean expression. But I do not know why and where I have to add it?

Comment: `why do error occurs? ` What error?

Comment: Add *what* boolean expression *where*? What is your program expected to be doing and how do you know it doesn't do that?

Comment: @eerorika why do error occurs? Why do humans not fly like birds? Humankind has been puzzled by those questions since time immemorial.

Comment: Please note, that in this loop you will find not the largest, but smallest number by which `i` is divisible.

Answer (score 2):

(Inspired by Alexandrescu's CppCon 2019 talk)

Recall, that the control check on the loop is not necessary - we know that `X % 1` is 0 for any X. Also, in-line with Alexandrescu's commitment to endless loops, we could rewrite the loop as following (it will have an added bonus of making it correct, but also will improve it's performance):

```
if (n <= 1) {
    return;
}
largest = n - 1;
for (;; --largest) {
    if (n % largest == 0)
        break;
}

// Here largest is usable
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this loop

```
while( i > 0){
    if ( n % i == 0){
        largest = i;
    }
    i --;
}
```

for example like

```
while( i > 0 && n % i != 0 ) i--;

if ( i ) largest = i;
```

Also instead of the type int you should use the type unsigned int. Otherwise the user can enter a negative number. In this case the loop does not make sense.

Using your approach the program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    unsigned int n = 0, largest = 1;

    std::cout << "enter a non-negative number: ";

    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        unsigned int i = n - 1;

        while ( i > 0 && n % i != 0 ) i--;

        if ( i ) largest = i;
    }

    std::cout << "The largest own divisor is " << largest << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```